# How to convert jquery to React JS when ul empty adding li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I uses React JS with Typescript.

I want add LI tag to the UL tag when the UL tag is empty using createElement method.

Here is code I found out the exact what I want but it's jquery.

```
$('ul').on('keyup keydown', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
    if (! $this.html()) {
        var $li = $('<li></li>');
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        
       var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
       
        range.collapse(false);
        range.insertNode($li.get(0));
        range = range.cloneRange();
        range.selectNodeContents($li.get(0));
        range.collapse(false);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        
    } else {
        var $nonLI = $this.find(':not(li, br)');
        if ($nonLI.length) {
            $this.contents().replaceWith(function() {
                return '<li>' + '</li>';
            });
        }                   
    }     
});
```

and here is my react code

index.tsx

```
const Bullet: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const onKeyHandler = ()> {
    // what I want events... but didn't work it...
    const divEL = document.querySelector('#div-area');
    const ulEL = document.querySelector('#ul-element');
    divEL?.childNodes.forEach((node) => {
      if (node === ulEL) {
        console.log('i find it!');
      } else {
        console.log('nooop!!');
      }
    });
  }

  return (
        <div id="div-area" contentEditable suppressContentEditableWarning>
          <ul
            id="ul-element"
            onKeyUp={onKeyHandler}
            onKeyDown={onKeyHandler}
          >
            <li />
          </ul>
        </div>
  )
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the beauty of React is that you can think in terms of components and leave the DOM manipulation to React itself. Instead of asking how you can add an li tag when a ul is empty by manipulating the DOM directly, try thinking about what's going to be rendered in that ul and how that is going to change the UI that you display. Consider trying something like the following (which is a little contrived, I hope you get the idea):

```
const Bullet: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [myListData, setMyListData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchListData = async () => /* ... */;
    const data = await fetchListData();
    setMyListData(fetchListData)
  })

  return (
        <div id="div-area" contentEditable suppressContentEditableWarning>
          <ul
            id="ul-element"
            onKeyUp={onKeyHandler}
            onKeyDown={onKeyHandler}
          >
            // Now we'll render our list if it's populated, and render an empty <li /> element if it's empty!
            {myListData.length === 0 ? <li /> : {myListData.map(node => <MyDataNode node={node} />)}}
          </ul>
        </div>
  )
}
```